# infura.info error method post

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, web3-providers

I have deployed a smart contract in the testnet using MetaMask and a solidity online compiler(injected web3):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.7;
contract SimpleStorage {

  uint public storedData;
  string public name = "ahmed";
  event Print(uint);

  function SimpleStorage(uint initialValue) {
    storedData = initialValue;
  }

  function set(uint x) returns (uint){
    storedData = x;
    Print(storedData);
    return storedData;
  }

  function get() constant returns (uint retVal) {
    return storedData;
  }
}
```

I used the [ropsten.infura.io](http://ropsten.infura.io) provider to interact with the contract in the testnet 
I can call string "name" from console and it returns value successfully.
But when i want to call the function "set" or "get", I got an error:

```
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
```

This is my js file to call function:

```
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/ahmed_charef"));

contractAddress = "0x752fB8626c5bEf519EfC661F6694fbE497405FfE"
ABI  = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"storedData","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"x","type":"uint256"}],"name":"set","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"get","outputs":[{"name":"retVal","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"initialValue","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Print","type":"event"}]

myContract = web3.eth.contract(ABI).at(contractAddress);

myContract.name(function(err, res){
    console.log(res); 
  })

function voteForCand() {

  myContract.set("20");
}
```

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

Calling **a function that is not a constant function** requires gas for execution, so you need to provide an unlocked from address to invoke this call.

For example:

```
myContract.set('20', { from: web3.eth.accounts[0] })
```

I just tried this and it works:
[txHash](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x1c9c4162a44e77549806b83c79e310533393136dc08367891c708881de981d13)